# ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence

Tags: sql, spring, oracle, spring-jdbc

I am getting org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL

```
UPDATE responses 
SET    version_no = ( version_no + 1 ), 
       read_status = 0, 
       tslastmodified = SYSDATE 
WHERE  responseid IN (SELECT responseid 
                      FROM   responses 
                      WHERE  read_status = 1 
                             AND tslastmodified < SYSDATE - 45 / ( 24 * 60 ) 
                             AND id IN (SELECT id 
                                        FROM   emp))
```

; SQL state [24000]; error code [1002]; ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence

JAVA code :

```
getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(SurveyQuery.UPDATE_INPROCESS, Integer.class);
```

Please let me know what is wrong in above query

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your `UPDATE` statement to something like below

```
UPDATE RESPONSES SET VERSION_NO=(VERSION_NO+1), 
READ_STATUS=0, 
TSLASTMODIFIED = SYSDATE 
WHERE READ_STATUS = 1 
AND TSLASTMODIFIED < SYSDATE - 45/(24*60) 
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM EMP
            WHERE RESPONSES.ID = EMP.ID)
```

Note: Though you can use the above modified query but I doubt the said error is because of the posted update statement. From [Documentation](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01002.php) it looks like the cause of the above error could be

> When you perform a FETCH on an active cursor after all records have
>   been fetched.
>
> (OR)
>
> When you perform a FETCH on a SELECT FOR UPDATE after a COMMIT has
>   been issued.

Comment: wanted to know whether the update query that you have written is more efficient than the first one

Comment: Should be since in your query you are using 2 subqueries, out of which one is unnecessary. Test it for yourself and see.

Comment: Your rewrite avoids having a sub-query which drives from the table being updated.  I too can't understand how that would throw ORA-01002, but we haven't seen the Spring/Hibernate code, so we don't know what it attempts in the way of locking or transaction management.

Comment: I'm curious why you use `getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject` instead of `getJdbcTemplate().update`